# Getting IP addresses through sniffing

Tags: ip, wifi, gateway, address, sniffing

Is it possible to know the gateway address of a wireless AP that I'm not connected to through sniffing? Airodump-ng can show MAC addresses of the AP and the clients associated but doesn't show IP addresses.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why are you attempting this? You are aware that this is a site for professional sysadmins, i.e. those who setup systems such as this. I have a feeling this is a bit like you've walked into a police station asking for tips on how to rob a bank.

Comment: If there are clients connected, that means that someone within a couple hundred feet of you is connected. Ask around. Should we migrate this to socialengineering.stackexchange.com?

Comment: this is old, but if you are coming here to ask , and incapable of figuring this out - just stop while you are ahead and haven't done anything illegal yet

Answer (score 4):

If the network is open (unencrypted) then yes; you can capture the full packets of connected clients and see the addresses in IP and ARP packets.

If the network is encrypted, then no; all of the layer 3 communication is encapsulated in encrypted packets at all times, and the MAC addresses on the transmissions is all you can get without breaking the encryption.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question. (I wanted to determine the exact same thing.)

Answer (score 3):

Despite the fact I've only just joined the site yesterday - I have to say coming on here and asking this without putting anything in doesn't look impressive - if you had a heap of questions/answers relating to network security then I could believe you with to increase your knowledge to help protect your own network by attempting penetration testing.

However if that was that case you would probably either know the answer to, or how to find the answer to your own question.